# error:Error pasing XML:unbound prefix for <translate

Tags: android, animation, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate                 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="0"
 andriod:toXDelta="10"
 android:duration="1000"
 android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

in my code I keep getting and error for the `<translate>` saying it's an unbound prefix. I'm working on the sudoku project for learning the android os programming and this has me at stand still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening here but when I cut and paste the xml code from your question, then I received the same unbound prefix error.

However, when I typed it out from scratch, it was all good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXDelta="0"
  android:toXDelta="10"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:interpolator="@anim/cycle7"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" >
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="10"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty obvious. There's no xmlns="xxx" declaration, so there's no xmlns declaration for the empty prefix. You can predeclare xmlns bindings. Can't remember how; but that's the solution.